# How to put 2 limits in javaScript for the same number, one for digits and the second one for decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I m having this problem. I want a limitation of 15 characters for a number and 3 character for the same number only for decimals. So my final number can be a number of maximum 15 digits but if I want after "." to able to add 3 more decimals. So my number can t be bigger than 15 characters only if I have decimals (3 maxim).
Hope I was clear enough. 
Thanks.

Comment: So it can be 19chars?  15+"."+3?  or is 15 the hard-max, so 15 without decimals or 13+"."+1dp or 11+"."+3dp (etc) ?

Comment: It can be 19chars only 15 + "." + 3, or without "." max 15.

Comment: Is string value of `<input>` element?

Comment: yes it is. I have a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` `/^\d{15}(?:\.\d{3}|$)/` to match fifteen digits, or fifteen digits followed by `.` followed by three digits, followed by end of string

```js
var re = /^\d{15}(?:\.\d{3}|$)/;
console.log(re.test("1234567891.23456")); // false
console.log(re.test("123456789123456.123")); // true
console.log(re.test("12345678912345")); // false
console.log(re.test("123456789123456")); // true
```

Using `pattern` attribute at `<input>` element

```css
:invalid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input required pattern="^\d{15}(?:\.\d{3}|$)">
```

Comment: @AndreiChivu See updated post. Reduced `RegExp` by several characters.

Comment: I still have some problems, your validation fails for number with less than 15 characters. I want to be able to have values like 123, or 123.123.

Comment: @AndreiChivu What did you mean by _"It can be 19chars only 15 + "." + 3, or without "." max 15"_ ? Does using the suggested edit to `RegExp` resolve issue described at previous comment?

Answer (score 1):

this should be the correct one:

as asked by OP, there can either 15 characters or 11+.+3=15 characters

```css
:invalid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input required pattern="(\d{15}$)|(\d{11}\.\d{3}$)">
```

Comment: _"It can be 19chars only"_ `11 + 4 === 15 && 11 + 4 !== 19`

Answer (score 1):

this is working as you want:

```
$("input").keydown(function(event){
       var value=$("input").val();
   if($.inArray(event.keyCode, [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,46,8, 9, 27, 13, 110,190])>=0)
     {
    if(value.length>=15)
    {
      if((event.keyCode==190 || value.indexOf(".")>0) && value.length<19)
         {
           return true;
          }
        else
        {
          return false;
       }
    }}
else
{
 return false;
}
});
```

Comment: @AndreiChivu If this will work for you please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: It partially works and only for Chrome. with your code I m able to enter for a number shorter than 15 more than 3 decimals ..witch is not correct. And as I mention before this type of code has problems with other browsers like opera or Mozilla.

Comment: and I can t use backspace for a full number.